# Sympy nsolve TypeErrors

Tags: python, typeerror, sympy

I have two variables.
The variable `Eqs_LHS` contains the equations

```
-2*p34 + u1 + u2 + atanh(2*p34 - 1) = 0 
-2*p24 + u1 + u3 + atanh(2*p24 - 1) = 0 
2*p24 + 2*p34 + u1 + u4 + atanh(-2*p24 - 2*p34 - 1) = 0 
2*p24 + 2*p34 + u2 + u3 + atanh(-2*p24 - 2*p34 - 1) = 0 
-2*p24 + u2 + u4 + atanh(2*p24 - 1) = 0 
-2*p34 + u3 + u4 + atanh(2*p34 - 1) = 0
```

and the variable `unknownP_U` contains the symbols `(p24, p34, u1, u2, u3, u4)`

I want to find a numerical solution to this system of equations using 
sympy.nsolve(), which requires an initial guess vector.

If I use

```
nsolve(Eqs_LHS, unknownP_U, (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))
```

Or with a similar initial guess vector, I get a TypeError:

`TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 6 arguments (1 given`)

If instead I use a numpy array or a list as a initial guess vector, I get a different TypeError:

```
TypeError: cannot create mpf from array
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
from sympy import *
var('p24, p34, u1, u2, u3, u4')

Eqs_LHS = (-2*p34 + u1 + u2 + atanh(2*p34 - 1) ,
-2*p24 + u1 + u3 + atanh(2*p24 - 1) ,
2*p24 + 2*p34 + u1 + u4 + atanh(-2*p24 - 2*p34 - 1) ,
2*p24 + 2*p34 + u2 + u3 + atanh(-2*p24 - 2*p34 - 1) ,
-2*p24 + u2 + u4 + atanh(2*p24 - 1) ,
-2*p34 + u3 + u4 + atanh(2*p34 - 1) )

unknownP_U = (p24, p34, u1, u2, u3, u4)

sol = nsolve(Eqs_LHS, unknownP_U, (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))
print(sol)
```

No errors. The output has some complex numbers.

Comment: By default, nsolve finds only real solutions to real systems (given a real initial point). The problem is that your system contains complex numbers; the values of atanh when its argument is outside of (-1,1). Try to rearrange the system so that they do not arise: for example, replace `A + atanh(B) = 0` by `tanh(A) + B = 0`.

Comment: I'd take that as a sign that there is no real solution. What happens is that iteration diverges to infinity, where the derivative of tanh is extremely small. Since this derivative goes in the denominator of a formula in Newton's method, the error occurs.

Comment: That said, SymPy is not the best tool for numeric solutions. SciPy has more to offer: see [fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy.optimize.fsolve) and [root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root).